# @ character allowed in URL, dangerous?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, codeigniter-url

From the CodeIgniter config.php file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Would it be safe for me to add the `@` character to this list of permitted characters? What are the risks?

Thanks

Comment: It’s rather `%` that is not allowed.

Comment: @Gumbo, It should be permitted -- read the code comment again.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ: So `foo%~bar` is permitted but obviously invalid.

Comment: @chigley: What kind of sanity check is this used for?

Comment: @chigley, "CodeIgniter config.php"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its safe, see the list of unsafe chars

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 3):

@ is used to prepend username and possibly password to URL-s that require HTTP auth. How that is insecure I can not tell from this comment. Theoretically, depending on the context you may not want users to enter such url-s.

Other than that this kind of security check is a bit .. dumb, there are increasing amounts of top-level domains out there that use characters others than ASCII, Russia was allocated .рф, Mainland China got .中國, there are many more examples.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Answer (score 1):

It is not listed here to prevent this kind of url:

```
http://mybank.com-some-very-long-string@hacker.com/
```

This would go to `hacker.com` while looking like `mybank.com` to casual ussr.

Comment: See `URL.php` and `Router.php` -- it is used after explode the url into segments.

Comment: this might be obvious but having @ filter doesn't prevent this kind of url obvious because as you said, it goes to hacker.com and it's up to hacker.com to parse it. Secondly, you really expect the average user to know the difference of a few character sequence in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't, unless you encode it. The unencoded `@` is reserved for a special meaning, like an FTP user (monty@ftp.python.com) or an email address (monty.python@camelot.com).

So, regardless of the temptation, don't do it. Why would you want to anyway?

Answer (score 1):

RFC 1738 permits only the following characters in the path segment of a URI: `A-Za-z0-9_\-\.!~*\'"(),` (not the query part)

Answer (score -1):

You can find more specific details about it here, it suggest you how you can use dangerous characters too using encoding

http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/
more over javascript:could be danger

You can use &lt replacing < signs and other special danger characters with respective substitutes.